# VMware: Why is zero-filling ext4 free space needed to shrink *.vmdk files?

Tags: ext4, vmware

On my Linux Mint 17.2 VMware guest, `df -h` was reporting my total disk usage steady at about 10GB total. I'm using this machine for Ruby on Rails development inside a Windows host running Workstation 12.1.1 Pro.

The `*.vmdk` files kept on steadily growing to approx 100GB. Trying to shrink with `vmware-vdiskmanager -k` or `vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrinkonly` made no difference.

I have `Filesystem features: has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize`. A more complete `dumpe2fs` output is [available](http://pastebin.com/p7TLqKRF).

Running `e4defrag /` and `e2fsck -E discard` didn't allow any more space to be reclaimed (I killed the shrink after the first few vmdks (which started at around 6GB) showed no sign of shrinking.)

What finally did the trick was filling all free space with `NUL`bytes:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=wipefile bs=1M; sync; rm wipefile`

I could now shrink to a total `*.vmdk` size of 15.6GB with `vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrinkonly`.

That's about 85GB space saving on a VM with 10GB actual data.

It seems that `ext4` is not re-using previously used blocks when asked for an unused block, often preferring to give out never-before-used blocks.

**Questions**

1. Having old data hanging around longer seems less secure. Why would `ext4` not re-use recently-used blocks as soon as possible?
2. Is there a way to force `ext4` to reuse just-used blocks?
3. Is there a way to prevent a VMware guest's `*.vmdk` files from continually growing without needing to `0`-fill free space on a regular basis?

   - How do you safely (eg not entirely filling the filesystem) automate this?

Comment: Would you mind to add more technical details, and the reasons you are suspicious?

Comment: How now? Anything you can think of that I could check out?

Comment: Some things are not clear. From the context, are you mentioning the use of ext4 *inside* the VM? What is the VM doing? What you suspect you can be changed? How are the filesystems created and defined on the VM side? Can reorganising the partitions make a difference? The fs management is highly dependent on the kernel and layer 7 usage, which you have not described. As dding to zero the free space, it should not making a difference except when making tar.gzs of dd.

Comment: I've overhauled the question. The `dd` definitely was the trick and it's quite a common hack in shrinking linux guest `*.vmdk` files. The real question is: "why should it be necessary?"

Comment: after using dd, how do you shrink? (please add to the question)

Comment: It seems like a limitation with VMWare workstation 12.5.1. Even with `scsi0.virtualDev = "pvscsi"` in my `.vmx`, `lsscsi -l` gives `scsi_level=3` which doesn't support `UNMAP`.

Answer (score 4):

No filesystems zero out blocks of deleted files, they just ***mark those clusters as available***. That's why recovery tools can recover deleted files if they weren't overwritten by other files. If filesystem drivers reuse those blocks ASAP then you'll no longer have the ability to recover accidentally erased files and customers will cry, and if they must overwrite the clusters with zero then performance will suffer severely.

Files that are expected to be stored securely should be encrypted instead of leaving as-is on disk. If needed, use [shredder tools](https://askubuntu.com/q/57572/253474) like [shred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_(Unix)) on Unix and [ccleaner drive wiper, eraser, sdelete...](http://www.howtogeek.com/72130/learn-how-to-securely-delete-files-in-windows/) on Windows to delete securely.

About VMDK, you should know that it stores sectors in a [sparse format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), just like VHD, VDI or any other VM's dynamically-sized virtual disk image format. Therefore zeroing out sectors mark them as *not needed* anymore and the compactor will leave them out, resulting in a smaller file. Any non-zero sectors have to be stored explicitly because the VM doesn't know whether the sector belongs to a deleted file or not

Using `dd if=/dev/zero` is a bad way because

> - it is slow;
> - it makes the disk image (temporarily) grow to its maximal extent;
> - it (temporarily) uses all free space on the disk, so other concurrent write actions may fail.

as mentioned in the [`zerofree` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/zerofree.8.html). Use a tool specifically for zeroing out disks like [`zerofree`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/zerofree) instead.

There's no way to prevent a virtual disk image from expanding, because what would you expect if more data need to be written on the disk? Even in case files are deleted, their data are still on disk and take space in the image file. If you don't want the file to grow, the only way is making it **fixed-sized** on creation.

Comment: In the case of deleted files, `btrfs` and `ext4` pass down a discard for blocks which are no longer in use. However, [Linux distributions check the SCSI version, and unless it is version 5 or greater, it does not send UNMAPs](http://cormachogan.com/2015/05/07/vsphere-6-0-storage-features-part-8-vaai-unmap-changes/). VMware's driver says SCSI version 3 for me :(

Comment: I think in this case it's easier to try Virtualbox, which supports almost all common virtual harddisk file types. Or simply write script to zero and compact the vmdk file automatically like what I'm using if you're allowed to shutdown the VM at night

Comment: I've found VirtualBox to be buggy in the Hypervisor UI arena, which didn't inspire me to use it for the VM itself. My `zero-balloon` script is very rough... do you have one that nearly-but-doesn't-quite fill the partitions to avoid disk full conditions?

Comment: Actually, I'm using `LUKS` now, so zero-filling would actually make things worse... perhaps using `LVM` with thin-provisioning with the provisioned size no greater than the actual size is actually the way to go as it processes discards sensibly

Comment: lvm is the way to go, it does solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, from security standpoint it would be better to immedeately erase any unused blocks. The reason that is not done (ignoring `chattr` secure-delete flag and patches) is performance. The same is a reson for not using any recenty freed block - it would lead to heavy fragmentations which hurts performance.
2. No, not really. You could make your whole image much smaller (formatting it to say `15G` and then growing only if/when that becomes necessary.) - then it will never grow bigger than 15Gb.
3. You can try to mount filesystem with `discard` option - see `fstab(5)`, but I'm not sure if your [vmware will heed this](http://cormachogan.com/2015/05/07/vsphere-6-0-storage-features-part-8-vaai-unmap-changes/)

Comment: As mentioned, `e2fsck -E discard` didn't do anything, so I doubt that making realtime discards `mount`ing with `-o discard` will do anything. Also I get: `fstrim: /: FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported` - trim is not listed as a feature of the virtual SATA device in `hdparm -I /dev/dm-0` output.

Comment: @TomHale did you look at the link? There are changes in vmware config that need to be done too before it could work. But I can't vouch for that part, as said in answer...

Comment: I'm currently stuck getting `hdparm` to correctly see virtual SCSI disks as required by that link - see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305444/vmware-sg-io-bad-missing-sense-data-on-a-fresh-scsi-virtual-disk).

Comment: `lsscsi -lL` is seeing a virgin SCSI disk as SCSI level 3, so UNMAPwon't work as per your link. I ended up shrinking the filesystem, Logical Volume, Volume Group and Physical Volume... and VMware *.vmdk files are still twice the size the used partition after the shrink. Oh well.

Comment: @TomHale you should zero-fill all remaining space first to get it smaller - grow `PV` and `VG` to maximum size available, create new logical volume with all free space, and then clear it with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/unusedLV bs=1m`. Only after that you should `lvremove` it and shrink `VG` and `PV`, and then run vmware image shrinking tools.

Comment: Thanks @MatijaNalis, but I'm after something that doesn't require manual intervention. It's even more critical now I'm using LUKS.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because writing a lot of NULs to the VMDK made it reclaim all the deleted blocks and allocate them to `wipefile`. However, why `e4defrag` did not do the same is something I do not understand.

Comment: What do you mean by 'writing to the VMDK'? I'm confused as every filesystem change in the guest is reflected in the VMDK fikes.