# VMware: `SG_IO: bad/missing sense data` on a fresh SCSI virtual disk

Tags: vmware, scsi

I'm running VMWare Workstation 12.1.1 Pro under Windows 10, with a guest Linux Mint 17.2 with virtual hardware version 11.

My only current disk is a virtual SATA.

When I add a virtual SCSI device at 0:0, (creating a new 0.4GB disk as a test) I'm getting the error shown below.

I re-installed `vmware-tools` after creating the SCSI disk. No change. I also tried upgrading the virtual hardware to version 12.

What am I missing?

> ```
> @ravi@boxy:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda 
>
> /dev/sda:
> SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> ATA device, with non-removable media
>   Model Number:       ��������@���������p����@�
>   Serial Number:      ���=�D���i@���
>   Firmware Revision:  ��i�
> Standards:
>   Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x00d8) 
>   Supported: 11 10 
>   Likely used: 11
> Configuration:
>   CHS addressing not supported
>   LBA    user addressable sectors:   38024320
>   Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
>   device size with M = 1024*1024:       18566 MBytes
>   device size with M = 1000*1000:       19468 MBytes (19 GB)
>   cache/buffer size  = unknown
> Capabilities:
>   LBA, IORDY(may be)(cannot be disabled)
>   Standby timer values: spec'd by Vendor
>   R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 255 Current = 255
>   Recommended acoustic management value: 234, current value: 0
>   DMA: not supported
>   PIO: unknown
>      *    reserved 69[2]
>      *    reserved 69[6]
>      *    SET MAX SETPASSWORD/UNLOCK DMA commands
> Security: 
>   Master password revision code = 14080
>   10min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 119808min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 
> Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 0000000000000000
>   NAA     : 0
>   IEEE OUI    : 000000
>   Unique ID   : 000000000
> Integrity word not set (found 0x0000, expected 0x79a5)
> @ravi@boxy:~$
> ```

Comment: Do you get better results if you try using `sdparm(8)` instead? How is disk detected in `dmesg(8)`

Comment: Cheers! It comes up sane in that tool and `lsscsi`. I've made an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong tool:

`hdparm`(8) - get/set SATA/IDE device parameters

For SCSI, use:

`sdparm`(8) - access SCSI modes pages; read VPD pages; send simple SCSI commands

`lsscsi`(8) - list SCSI devices (or hosts) and their attributes